# Store pattern names in variables, and use them in Condition (/;)

Tags: pattern-matching, string-manipulation, symbols, expression-construction

I am trying to create patterns whose form is not hard-coded, and which are not explicitly directly written. For that I want to use one list of pattern names to name some parts of a `StringExpression`:

```
patternNames = {p1, p2, p3};
```

and the different pattern objects that will make up the `StringExpression` coming in a different list:

```
patternObjects = {"a" .., "b" .., "c" ..};
```

The `StringExpression` will then look like:

```
patterns = StringExpression @@ MapThread[Pattern, {patternNames, {"a" .., "b" .., "c" ..}}]

(* p1 : ("a" ..) ~~ p2 : ("b" ..) ~~ p3 : ("c" ..) *)
```

To impose a condition on the matched strings (e.g. equal length), normally we would use the names in a `Condition` written explicitly:

```
 StringCases[{"aaaaaabbbcccc1234dddddabcdefg"},
 {p1 : ("a" ..) ~~ p2 : ("b" ..) ~~ p3 : ("c" ..)} /; Equal @@ StringLength /@ {p1, p2, p3}]

(* {{"aaabbbccc", "abc"}} *)
```

but since I don't know beforehand how many names there will be, I am putting the condition on the list of names, rather than on each of them one by one:

```
StringCases[{"aaaaabbccc1234dddddabcdefg"}, 
 patterns /; Equal @@ StringLength /@ patternNames]
```

However, when the condition is evaluated, it is not being evaluated on the matched string, but instead it is being applied on the symbols themselves. This is the error I'm getting:

[image]

When I write the name symbols explicitly they get highlighted in green, what makes them behave differently. Is there a way to make the symbols specified in the list container behave in that way as well, as pattern names rather than symbols on their own?

I've thought about functions of the sort of `Unevaluated` or `Hold`, but have not found any specifically directed to this use and have not managed to make it work so far. I'd appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: Have you tried using `With[]` for injection? `StringCases[{"aaaaaabbbcccc1234dddddabcdefg"}, With[{pTmp = patternNames}, Condition[patterns, Equal @@ StringLength /@ pTmp]]]`

Comment: @J.M. this did work but I don't understand why, could you please help me to understand? I was not familiar with that concept of injection